# How to scale out Azure Storage Queues

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am wondering how Azure handles the geographic distribution of Storage Queues?
If I have a storage queue setup in one region and then I want to scale out to other regions, what happens? Do I need to write code to handle the Queues separately?
For example Amazon Web Services have DynamoDB which is globally distributed out of the box and will provide the same performance everywhere.

Comment: did you find any other details on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more logical comparison would be between Windows Azure Tables and DynamoDB. That said:

Windows Azure queues are assigned to a specific data center, and you can create additional queues in other data centers. Typically you'd place your queue in the same DC as your cloud service working with the queue, but there's no requirement there (you'll get better performance and no outbound bandwidth charges when you access same-DC queues).

DynamoDB, from what I've read [here](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), has the same model: Choose your data center for a table. Data is distributed across servers in the same region, not multiple regions (in other words, if you choose N. Virginia, that's where your data access point is).

Regarding your statements of DynamoDB "being globally distributed out of the box" and providing "the same performance everywhere" - I don't think that's the case (at least, I can't find any evidence supporting that assertion). Rather, DynamoDB is replicated to additional data centers for fault tolerance, as is Windows Azure Storage.

Bottom line: you'd have to manage resources allocated to multiple data centers, whether Windows Azure Tables, Windows Azure Queues, or DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I will post another question how to sync distributed systems across different geographic regions.